# Pressing Backspace in Google Search doesn't go back one page

Tags: google-search

Using Google Instant with autocomplete turned on, I'm unable to press the backspace button to go back to the previous page. When I press the backspace button, I do not have focus in the search input however the result of the backspace instead puts focus to the search input and removes the last character.

Is there a way to turn off this keyboard shortcut for the backspace that Google has overwritten for me so that the backspace button acts normally like any other website when its result is to take me back to the previous page?

I've found a Chrome extension: Reclaim Backspace (Google Instant), but I rather have this option saved to my Google account preferences and not to run an extension. Also, I'd like to remain Google Instant and autocompletion turned ON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> instead of <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Comment: Hmm, at least this is a short cut that actually works. I'll just have to change my backspace habit for this :) Thanks Zach!